# SQL Server views - select column via ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

i'm having problems trying to select columns when generating views.

The view would be generated using the two following tables:

Teams Table:

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦══╗
║ teamID ║   teamName   ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬══╣
║      1 ║ exampleTeam  ║  ║
║      2 ║ exampleTeam2 ║  ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩══╝
```

Fixtures Table (homeTeamID and awayTeamID are both linked to teamID in Teams table):

```
    ╔═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
    ║ fixtureID ║ homeTeamID ║ awayTeamID ║
    ╠═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
    ║         1 ║          1 ║          2 ║
    ╚═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

When generating the view, I would like to select and display the teamName field rather than teamID for both teams playing in a fixture. The intended view results would be displayed as follows:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ fixtureID ║  homeTeam   ║   awayTeam   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║         1 ║ exampleTeam ║ exampleTeam2 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I would be greatful for any tips as to how I could go about achieving this. 
I apologize in advance for the terrible formatting.

Comment: Hint:  Use two joins.

Comment: The same way you would do a similar select. Just add create view to it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way in the sql query

```
SELECT F.fixtureID, 
       HomeTeam.teamName as homeTeam,
       AwayTeam.teamName as awayTeam   
FROM Fixtures F
INNER JOIN Teams HomeTeam
ON F.homeTeamId = HomeTeam.teamID 
INNER JOIN Teams AwayTeam
ON F.awayTeamId = AwayTeam.teamID
```

The create view query will look like

```
CREATE VIEW FixtureView
AS

SELECT F.fixtureID, 
           HomeTeam.teamName as homeTeam,
           AwayTeam.teamName as awayTeam   
    FROM Fixtures F
    INNER JOIN Teams HomeTeam
    ON F.homeTeamId = HomeTeam.teamID 
    INNER JOIN Teams AwayTeam
    ON F.awayTeamId = AwayTeam.teamID
```